# Dell laptop connecting to an external monitor - everything looks too big

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution, dell-xps, pixels

I have a Dell XPS Studio 1640 which displays in 1900 by 1200 res. Recently, I bought a 19" monitor for it which has a maximum resolution of about 1300 or so.

The problem though is when I plug it in, the icons and the windows look massive and take a lot more real estate. I think this is because Windows is defining everything based in pixels. So because my XPS normally displays everything in 1900px, Windows knows it requires a certain number of pixels to make an icon appear at the right size on the screen. On a 1300px screen however, that number of pixels is going to look about 30-40% times bigger and take much more space.

My question is, is it possible for Windows to somehow render the icons and windows and fonts with different numbers of pixels on different monitors?

I'm probably making a mess of explaining the problem, please ask if you do not understand the problem as I would really like a resolution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course everything is going to be larger on the external monitor. It has a far lower resolution than the XPS monitor. Just because the external monitor is physically larger (just guessing here) doesn't necessarily mean you get more screen real-estate. If all is correctly configured, the best you can hope for is proper image scaling. The smallest it goes is 100%.